# Why AND a uint32 value with 0xFFFFFFFF?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

A friend of mine was looking through [this open-source SSL code](https://github.com/polarssl/polarssl/blob/master/library/sha2.c#L247) at the functions for handling SHA encryption, and noticed this odd snippet:

```
ctx->total[0] += (uint32_t) ilen;         // ilen is of type size_t
ctx->total[0] &= 0xFFFFFFFF;              

if( ctx->total[0] < (uint32_t) ilen )
    ctx->total[1]++;
```

We can't figure out two things about this code.  First, it ANDs `ctx->total[0]` (of type `uint32_t`) with `0xFFFFFFFF`, which shouldn't do anything.  In binary, that's ANDing with all `1`s, which should yield the same value.  In my mind, then, these two lines are identical:

```
ctx->total[0] &= 0xFFFFFFFF;
ctx->total[0] =  ctx->total[0];
```

If I am right, why is this line there? Some security reason? If I am wrong, how and why?

Second, we don't understand when that `if` would ever be true, assuming the AND doesn't do anything.  If the AND does nothing, then the `if` is essentially:

```
if (ctx->total[0] < ctx->total[0])
```

which should never be true.  What are we missing?

---

If you want to see the header file to convince yourself that `ctx->total[0]` is of type `uint32_t`, or for whatever other reason, you can find that [here](https://github.com/polarssl/polarssl/blob/master/include/polarssl/sha2.h#L50).

Also, my first wild guess is that there's something sneaky happening when we cast `ilen` from `size_t` to `uint32_t`, but I'm still stuck and confused.

Comment: For the second part of your question, the `if` may evaluate to true if `ctx->total[0]` previously had non-zero value and adding `ilen` caused it to overflow.

Comment: the &= is most likely a holdover from [the change for revision 5c2364c2bac4c0c0c269235aa701ec7e07a1e00e](https://github.com/polarssl/polarssl/commit/5c2364c2bac4c0c0c269235aa701ec7e07a1e00e#diff-1915e6a1e0291577083c3d1c44a5482a), which moved the type from an unsigned long to a uint32_t, and didn't remove the line which now seems to be superflous

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First question:

You're right that this &ing is not needed for 32bit, my guess is - they're trying to prevent situations when `ctx->total[0]` is not 32bit (so even if somebody will change it or platform will have 64bit even for uint32_t type), so with this code they are 100% sure, without 99.99999% :)

Second question is easy:

Check how this code will work for values `ctx->total[0] == 0xFFFFFFFF` and `ilen == 1`

`ctx->total[0] += (uint32_t) ilen; // this will overflow and total[0] now 0`

```
if( ctx->total[0] < (uint32_t) ilen ) // 0<1 true
    ctx->total[1]++;
```

Answer (score 4):

The `if` is basically doing:

```
if (ctx->total[0] + (uint32_t) ilen < (uint32_t) ilen)
    ctx->total[1]++;
```

i.e. if adding `ilen` to `ctx->total[0]` is going to cause an overflow, then bump `ctx->total[1]`.  In other words it's performing the *carry* of the addition.

Comment: it's just 64-bit adder, why don't they use 64-bit type, it'll be much easier and possibly faster